# Add two columns of different dataframes taking into account missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add columns of two dataframes (A + B), so that the result (C) takes into account missing values ('---')?

**DataFrame A**

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, '---', 5]})

    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   ---
4   5
```

**DataFrame B**

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'B': [3, 4, 5, 6, '---']})

    B
0   3
1   4
2   5
3   6
4   ---
```

**Desired Result of A+B**

```
    C
0   4
1   6
2   8
3   ---
4   ---
```

Comment: Is it important for the value of your missing value to be indicated by "`---`"?

Comment: yes, that's how i get it delivered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the '---' with np.nan, add the columns and fillna with '---'

```
(a['A'].replace('---', np.nan)+b['B'].replace('---', np.nan)).fillna('---')
```

You can assign the result to a new dataframe or an existing one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.assign(C = (a['A'].replace('---', np.nan)+b['B'].replace('---', np.nan)).fillna('---'))
```

OR

```
a.assign(C = (a['A'].replace('---', np.nan)+b['B'].replace('---', np.nan)).fillna('---'))
```

Comment: Result is no dataframe anymore

Comment: This is a series, the result can be assigned to a new data frame or an existing one